# rails 4 - associations - is it possible to have a polymorphic association on one side of a many-through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a Has-Many:Through association , in which one side (AccessLevel ) is a defined model 'AccessLevel' , but the other side can be set for multiple resources

I defined a specific concern to be included in these models, and tried to use a polymorphic association

```
    class AccessLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :allowed_activities 
      has_many :actionable, through: :allowed_activities    
    end

    class AllowedActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :access_level
      belongs_to :actionable, polymorphic: true
    end


    class <Model> < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Authorizable
    end

    module Authorizable
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      included do
        has_many :allowed_activities, as: :actionable
        has_many :access_levels, through: :allowed_activities
      end
    end
```

is that a correct implementation or am I going to raise some unexpected collateral issues ?

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use has_many: :through on polymorphic object

I need to specify the source_type of each object ( Sheet, ...

```
  has_many :actionable_sheets, :through => :allowed_activities, :source => :actionable, :source_type => 'Sheet'
```